# Highchart Heatmaps x-axis wrong start position

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap, highmaps

I am trying to create a heatmap with some json data.

The x-axis start position is having an unwanted offset.

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/dLa09dgb/

Here is my Configuration:

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
      type: 'heatmap',
      inverted: false
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Highcharts extended heat map',
      align: 'left',
      x: 40
    },

    subtitle: {
      text: 'Temperature variation by day and hour through 2013',
      align: 'left',
      x: 40
    },

    xAxis: {
      title: {
        text: x
      },
      tickPixelInterval: 50,
      tickInterval: 0.1,
      min: 2,
      max: 3
    },

    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: y
      },
      tickPositions: category,
      startOnTick: false,
      endOnTick: false,
      tickWidth: 1,
      min: 0,
      max: 60,
      tickInterval: 5,
      tickPixelInterval: 50
    },

    colorAxis: {
      min: -100,
      max: 100
    },

    series: [{
      data: dataArr,
      colsize: 1,
      rowsize: 2,
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: 'Options<br/>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x} {point.y} <b>{point.value}</b>'
      }
    }]

});
```

Can anyone help me with the initial position. I want the x-axis to start and end without any extra spacing.

Comment: Please avoid giving screenshots (*or rather don't just have screenshots*), we can't work with them. Instead also give a fiddle or snippet we can modify. This will make it much easier for us to reproduce your example and give a definite answer.

Comment: You set a tick like 2, but your data begins from about 1, the same situation is in the max value.

Comment: @SebastianBochan: Yes, that's the problem. I have not yet found the solution. I am not sure if I am missing some configuration. 
Please let me know if you have any solution for it.